# nodejs createReadStream in functional programming

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I would like to have your feedback on the usage of `TaskEither` using [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/TaskEither.html) or another functional programming library for learning purposes:

- I am using a `Promise` when dealing with a nodejs stream,  is it a good solution to use a `Promise` in this way? What are the most straightforward alternatives?
- I am using `.run().then(...)` and `.fold` do you know a more succinct way to use my function?
- Can the same code be rewritten using `Either` without a `Promise`? Could you please provide ma a sample?

---

```
export const md5 = (path: string): TaskEither<string, string> => {
  const mkHash = (p: string) =>
    new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      const hash = createHash("md5");
      const rs = createReadStream(p);
      rs.on("error", (error: Error) => reject(error));
      rs.on("data", chunk => hash.update(chunk));
      rs.on("end", () => {
        return resolve(hash.digest("hex"));
      });
    });
  return tryCatch<string, string>(
    () => mkHash(path).then(x => x),
    message => `cannot create md5 hash: ${message}`
  );
};
```

---

```
it("should return right and create md5 hash for a file", () => {
    md5(fileName)
      .run()
      .then(e =>
        e.fold(console.log, r => {
          expect(r).toBe("SD8ddDad0756a93ded72b823b19dd877");
        })
      );
  });

  it("should return left with an error message", () => {
    md5(BAD_PATH)
      .run()
      .then(e =>
        e.fold(error => expect(error).toContain("ENOENT"), () => ({}))
      );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Fluture`](https://github.com/fluture-js/Fluture) for this task. It's a monadic lazy-evaluated alternative to promises library which can wrap or generate promises, but it can work alone altogether:

```
export const md5 = path =>
    Future ((reject, resolve) => {
      const hash = createHash ("md5")
      const rs = createReadStream (p)

      rs.on("error", reject);
      rs.on("data", chunk => hash.update (chunk));
      rs.on("end", () => {
        resolve (hash.digest ("hex"));
      })
    })
}

const eventualMd5 = md5('[path]')

Future.fork (console.error) (console.log) (eventualMd5)
```

Basically, you get the best of `Either` usable on asynchronous flows, and many related tools to bifurcate your code and handle both error and success scenarios.

Comment: do you know if fp-ts has something similar to Future? many thanks for your time!

Comment: @GibboK Hey. I don't know it. But I use Fluture in some project and I doubt that a non-dedicated project could be very concrete and extensive about *futures*. Give it a try :D

Comment: @GibboK I see. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: I was able to  rewrite this function using only `Either` without a `Promise`. I am still very interested in alternative solutions.

```
export const md5 = (path: string): Either<string, string> => {
  const BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
  let fd;
  try {
    fd = openSync(path, "r");
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    const hash = createHash("md5");
    let bytesRead;
    do {
      bytesRead = readSync(fd, buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      hash.update(buffer.slice(0, bytesRead));
    } while (bytesRead === BUFFER_SIZE);
    return right(hash.digest("hex"));
  } catch (error) {
    return left(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (fd !== undefined) {
         closeSync(fd);
    }
  }
};
```

---

```
  it("should return right and create md5 hash for a file", () => {
    const mk = md5(fileName);
    assert.strictEqual(mk.isLeft(), false);
    assert.strictEqual(mk.isRight(), true);
    assert.strictEqual(mk.value, "SS8dd3ad07e6a93ded72b823b19dd877");
  });

  it("should return left return an error message", () => {
    const mk = md5(BAD_PATH);
    assert.strictEqual(mk.isLeft(), true);
    assert.strictEqual(mk.isRight(), false);
    assert.strictEqual(mk.value.includes("ENOENT"), true);
  });
```